# Unable to open txt file in python

Tags: python, file-search

Whenever I try to access `.txt` file using python, I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/monty/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/tess.py", line 1, in 
>   f1=open("d:\test.txt")
>   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'd:\test.txt'

[image: Screenshot of error]

Please help!

Comment: Please show us your code that results in this error - without code, we really don't have much to go on in order to help you ...

Comment: use `open(r"d:\test.txt")` or `open("d:/test.txt")`.You need to know what is [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Your giving your file name as tess.py

Comment: You are using a windows machine. try using escape char to give absolute path. 
f = open("d:\\test.txt")

Answer (score 2):

Specify the path using double backward slash instead of single slash(i.e backward slash is escape charactor)

```py
fp = open('D:\\test.txt')
```

use single forward slash

```
fp = open('D:/test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal Python string literals, a backslash followed by some character has a special meaning. (Search for "string literals" and "escape sequence" or see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).) In this case, `\t` is the <kbd>tab</kbd> character. Try this:

```
>>> print("d:\test.txt")
d:  est.txt
```

So, when you try to open `"d:\test.txt"`, you're not opening the file `test.txt` in the root directory of the `d` drive but the file `d`<kbd>tab</kbd>`test.txt` in the current working directory.

There are multiple solutions to this. E.g. use a raw string literal: `r"d:\test.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

In python open() function basically needs 3 parametres: filename,mode and encoding. You have specified the filename but you still need to specify the mode. There are many modes but you will basically need 3 of them:

"w" ->(write mode) creates file and if file exists creates empty file
"a" ->(append mode) creates file and if file exists appends new data to previous data
"r" ->(read mode) reads precreated file.

and encoding parametre is for seeing the chracters correct:
ascii -> for english alphabet
utf-8 -> for most of the langugages in the world (use this)

So all in all you should use open function like this choose which fits your purpose:

```
fp=open("filename.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")
fp=open("filename.txt","a",encoding="utf-8")
fp=open("filename.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
```